# MacOS Sierra 10.12 MAMP php 5.3.29 apache is not starting

Tags: php, apache, mamp

Recently I updated my machine to MacOS Sierra 10.12 and it caused the MAMP 4.0 php version 5.3.29 (downloaded from MAMP website) makes Apache unable to start up.

I use terminal to start as per this command:
`sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start`

It throws the following error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 135 of /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf: Cannot load /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/modules/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/modules/libphp5.so, 10): Library not loaded: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/modules/libphp5.so\n  Reason: Incompatible library version: libphp5.so requires version 19.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 17.0.0

What is the issue?

Comment: any one could help me on this?

Comment: If it's of any help, 3.4 works without any problems on Sierra.

Comment: you mean MAMP 3.4? if yes, i have few projects running on this version 4.0 , if i downgrade  i need to do a lot of changes in php.ini, http.conf and it will give  errors.